# 'bundle is not installed' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am not good with devops. I had created a user called deploy. Previously I could ssh into my server then

> su deploy

and run

> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

.

Some days ago, I completely forgot that I had a user called deploy. Being the root user, I installed ruby using rvm. RVM was already installed.

Now I remember that I have a user called deploy. I ran su deploy then ran

> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

I got the following error

> The program 'bundle' is currently not installed. To run 'bundle'
>   please ask your administrator to install the package 'ruby-bundler'

Before I had installed ruby in super admin env I could run bundle in the deploy user env.

Is there a way to fix this?

PS: My capistrano deployment script is running without any problem even if  it is being deployed by the "deploy" user

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you ssh into the directory, at the directory, no `.ruby-version` file exists, so it use the default ruby version(run `which ruby` to see the exactly path), not the `rvm ruby version`, so it can't find the installed gems like `bundler`.

It's a environment problem.The capistrano deployment is working because you have assign ruby version in your deploy.rb like

```
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.2.2@zhitaotao'
```

so it can find correct ruby version, then find `installed` gems for the version.

The solution is add a file called `.ruby-version`, set the content to something like `ruby-2.3.1`.

If this not works, i suggest to reinstall `ruby`, `bundler`, and run `bundle install` for `deploy` user. We need to make sure that at the production directory, the ruby version is matched with the ruby version assigned in the deploy.rb.

Comment: I ran ruby -v in 'deploy' user env and got `The program 'ruby' is currently not installed. To run 'ruby' please ask your administrator to install the package 'ruby'`

Comment: the the problem is that the `ruby` bin is not in `PATH` now. you need to run `rvm install ruby-2.3.1`, then run `gem install bundler`, `bundle install`.

Comment: Already installed ruby-2.3.1. I got that when running rvm install .... This is getting so hard to fix.

Comment: @Raaz did you install it with `rvm` as pointed in @seaify - Freelancer 's comment?

Comment: @Dimitry_N, yes I did. Everything was working fine. Could it be that I installed ruby using rvm in super admin env and now deploy user is not finding ruby. Previously I had installed ruby using rvm. I even use RVM in my development env

Comment: @Raaz no, rvm can be installed for multiple users. What's getting returned when you run `which rvm` in production (ssh)?

Comment: @Dimitry_N I got this `/home/deploy/.rvm/bin/rvm`

Comment: @Dimitry_N, I removed ruby from super admin env and ran ran rvm install ruby-2.3.1 in deploy user env. I got  `mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1': Permission denied`

Comment: @Raaz hmm. Ok, run `rm -rf ~/.rvm` as root user. **Close out your current SSH session** and start another one as `deploy`. Now install `rvm` as `deploy` user and run `rvm install ruby 2.3.1`.

Comment: @Dimitry_N I got `mktemp: failed to create file via template '/home/ubuntu/rvm-exec-test.XXXXXX': Permission denied` while running \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Comment: that's wired, if u run as `deploy` user, should have nothing to do with the `ubuntu` user.